# Need to enable a button when click a button in another page in php/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

my Question is the 1st user logged in one page and has  one button.2nd user logged in his page .he has one disable button.when 1st user click the button the 2nd user disable button will be enabled in php/javascript.is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: in short, yes. But in order to get a worthwhile answer you'll have to provide more specific details

Comment: you can web socket: nodejs

Answer (score 1):

When user 1 click button 1 update database and on the other page check periodically with ajax if the table updated change the button attribute to enable. If you don't want to check periodically you can use node.js or similar approaches.